# Variance of sample mean in a binomial distribution

Tags: self-study, variance, binomial-distribution, descriptive-statistics

I'm trying to derive that the variance of `phat = pq/n`.  I'm unfortunately not getting that. Please tell me where I'm going wrong...

```
phat = x/n, where x is the # of successes in your trial and n is the number of samples
var(phat) = E[phat^2]-(E[phat])^2
= E[x^2/n^2] - p^2
= 1/n^2 * E[x^2] - p^2        

//E[x^2] seems like it should be np given that x=1 for success and 0 for failure

= np/n^2 - p^2
= p/n - p^2 = p(1-np)/n
```

which is not `pq/n`... arg!

Comment: Is the error in E[x^2] = np?  May be mixing up bernoulli and binomial random variables here.

Comment: I suggest starting with $\text{Var}(X)$. If that proves to be tricky (though I think it's easy enough), consider using factorial moments (i.e. rewrite in terms of $E[X(X-1)]$ + other terms). Alternatively, work from the Bernoulli and use elementary properties of mean and variance to get to moments of $X$. Once you have $\text{Var}(X)$ you can move to working $p$ in terms of it,

Comment: Thanks Glen.  I can prove pq/n via proving Var(X) = npq via Var(Xi) = pq via E[xi^2]-(E[xi])^2.  Was just wondering if I could do it via the methodology in the OP.  Seems like I'll have to use factorial moments to do that although I'll have to look that up.

Comment: Well, one thing that's wrong above is $E(X^2)$. It's not $np$

Comment: I think you have identified an important source of confusion: in the first line, "$x$ is the number of successes" whereas in the middle it suddenly has changed to a value that is either $0$ or $1$. For instance, when $n=2$ the first meaning of $x$ can have the values $0,1,2$ with probabilities $q^2,2pq,p^2$. The expectation of $x^2$ therefore equals $0^2q^2+1^2(2pq)+2^2p^2=2p(1+p)$: that's not equal to $np=2p$.

Comment: If you use indicator variables, X=X1+X2+...+Xn you can find that E(X^2)= np+n^2p^2-np^2
Then your result will follow